# Live template for react native in visual studio code

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I use live template in Android Studio or IntelliJ with shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> which allow me to use live template like `try catch block` or just type `iter` or `itar` for iterating a list. I wish to use same in react native development in Visual Studio Code. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can get this feather using a snippet plugin link is here [React native shippet](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jundat95.react-native-snippet)

This plugin helps you to write code easily, for example, type **imrc** and press tab

```
import React, { Component}  from 'react'  //imrc
```

Comment: Thanks dude to share this info.